# C# checking two values with one value changing every frame

Tags: c#

I've a problem with my code and I can't find a solution for it. I have three variables in my code:

- **FoodNeeded** is the amount of food needed
- **FoodAddedPerMinute** is the amount of food added per minute
- **Population** amount of population

The *FoodNeeded* variable is changing every frame. It depends on population but, the variable will always stay higher then 0.

If the FoodAddedPerMinute variable is greater then 0, it should do this:

```
Food_Added_PerMinute = Food_Added_PerMinute - Food_Needed * Time.deltaTime / 60;
```

But, if the FoodAddedPerMinute is **not** greater then 0, it should do this:

```
Food_Added_PerMinute = Food_Added_PerMinute + Food_Needed * Time.deltaTime / 60;
```

But, what if it is 0? Well I've tried >= and <= but it keeps looping and staying at zero (or a massive decimal number).

**EDIT:**
My whole point about these two calculations is that because if the **FoodAddedPerMinute** is not greater then 0, it should add up. Because if you do for example -2 + 1, you get -1. But if I used -2 - 1, I get -3 and that's not correct.

If the foodNeeded is *growing*, the FoodAddedPerMinute should **decrease**, and if foodNeeded is *decreasing*, it should **grow**. However, foodNeeded can not be less than zero. The reason why is because I'm using this: *Food_Needed = PlanetPopulation / 100000;*

**This is the looping issue**

[image]

**This happens when the number is greater then 0 (if statement)**
[image]

**And this happens when the number is not greater then 0 ( else statement )**
[image]

Comment: in both conditions you do the same calculation? is this on purpose? Could you please post the loop code? very unclear up to now

Comment: You posted the same code twice for both conditions.

Comment: "But, what if it is 0?" how do you actually want to handle this case? do nothing? or shall we decide for you (without any context) how to handle this case ?=!

Comment: why would `Food_Added_PerMinute` drop below `0`? That would mean food taken away wouldn't it?

Comment: can you post more code so that we can help to you. We don't know where you stopped.

Comment: I thank that you make mistake here `if the FoodAddedPerMinute variable is greater then 0` it maybe should be `if the FoodNeeded variable is greater then 0`

Comment: I've just written a console application to very crudely model your system. It works as I would expect, as the population and food needed increase then food added decreases as per your rules when the food added goes below 0 then it begins increasing again until the value moves above 0, at which point on the next frame it will decrease again - probably to below 0. You then reach this kind of lock where you decrease then increase then decrease then increase. Could you define definitively what you are trying to achieve? I think there might be an issue with the logic you're trying to implement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(Food_Added_PerMinute > 0)
{
    Food_Added_PerMinute = Food_Added_PerMinute - Food_Needed * Time.deltaTime / 60;
}
else
{
    Food_Added_PerMinute = Food_Added_PerMinute + Food_Needed * Time.deltaTime / 60;
}
```

is this what you are expecting

Comment: can you please post your if statement

Comment: @RaulFernandez, have you stepped through your code with a Debugger?  It should give you an idea of what is happening in each loop

Answer (score 1):

Okay so from what you've specified you should be able to achieve this with either an `if` statement or a `switch` statement. I will provide an example below as an if statement, the logic of this should work however if you're still seeing the issue you'll need to post your looping code too.

```
if (Food_Added_PerMinute > 0) {
    Food_Added_PerMinute = Food_Added_PerMinute - Food_Needed * Time.deltaTime / 60;
}
else {
    Food_Added_PerMinute = Food_Added_PerMinute + Food_Needed * Time.deltaTime / 60;
}
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, edit your question to include your frame code. It would also be worth using a debugger to step through the code and check exactly what is happening at the point of your condition and adding a watch to the `Food_Added_PerMinute` to check that it is actually being set.

Comment: better is to ask `if (Food_Added_PerMinute == 0){ ... } else{ ... }`

Comment: @MiOnIs, yes I think you're right. I've slightly misread the posters original question. I thought that he was wanting to handle 0 as a special case too.